# android imageview bottom to top animation / create imageview programmatically

Tags: android, android-animation

I have got an android app, i want to add at button click one of 10 images (R.raw.geld1-10) animated from before bottom of the activity to after its top.
I tried to get the numbers of pixels and multiply it with Math.random(), but the problem was that i pressed the button and it lagged hard without reason. It seemed that the generation and animation of this was too much for this  uithread. Besides it was NOT an avd, it was a modern smartphone (snapdragon).
Please can anyone help me and send me an alternative with no overhead.

Comment: what do you actually mean?  i couldn't get what you are trying to do...

Comment: i mean spawn a imageview (not displayed) and animate it (displayed) from bottom to top of activity (behind anything else) then destroy it

Comment: You can say I wanna get a picture falling bottom-up created and destroyed after its upfall

Comment: just use ValueAnimator/ObjectAnimator

Comment: And how? I am new to animations and generating views programmatically

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That solved it for me, thank you!

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html